# Can i change Cursor.Position to PointF on c#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to make Cursor Position as **PointF**

like this

```
 Cursor.Position=new PointF(457.630,480.9155);
```

Comment: As an explanation about why it is not possible: user interface elements (to which the cursor belongs in a wider sense) are normally designed to avoid anti-aliasing (otherwise they would look ugly <- unsharp edges!). So even if you could pass a PointF, you wouldn't see it because the coordinates would be rounded internally... in order to avoid anti-aliased rendering.

Comment: That is not sensible, the cursor has pixel precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly but you can convert a `PointF` to a `Point`.

`Point` already has two static methods that can help you with this:

`Cursor.Position = Point.Round(yourPointF);`

or

`Cursor.Position = Point.Truncate(yourPointF);`

Both of these lose information but in your case it's fine. You can't really set the mouse somewhere between two consecutive pixels.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Cursor.Position` is `System.Drawing.Point` wich is an integer value, so you would need to convert it to `Point`. You will lose some precision.

See it like this: if you have a grid of 10 x 10 pixels, you cannot say `SELECT PIXEL AT X = 5.7 AND Y = 6.2` because you cannot cut a pixel in half.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. You cannot position the cursor with sub-pixel accuracy.
If you have the X and Y coordinate as floats, you must first cast them to int, make a `Point` object, and then set the cursor position:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point( (int) 457.630F, (int) 480.9155F );
```